# Self Signed server certificate validation - SecTrustResultType.recoverableTrustFailure error

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I am using the CocoaMQTT (https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT) to access a Mosquitto broker which uses a self signed certificate.

The library provides a delegate function where I can validate the server certificate.

I am not a security expert and I come up with the following code.

```
func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    let caCertPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ca", ofType: "der")
    let caCertData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: caCertPath!))
    let caCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, caCertData! as CFData)
    
    let remoteCert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0)
    
    let policy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509()
    var optionalTrust: SecTrust?
    var trustResult: SecTrustResultType = SecTrustResultType.invalid
    guard
        SecTrustCreateWithCertificates([remoteCert] as CFArray, policy, &optionalTrust) == errSecSuccess,
        let caTrust = optionalTrust,
        SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(caTrust, [caCert] as CFArray) == errSecSuccess,
        SecTrustGetTrustResult(caTrust, &trustResult) == errSecSuccess
    else {
        completionHandler(false)
        return
    }
    
    switch trustResult {
        
    case .invalid:
        dprint("Invalid")
        
    case .proceed:
        dprint("Proceed")
        
    case .deny:
        dprint("Deny")
        
    case .unspecified:
        dprint("Proceed")
        
    case .recoverableTrustFailure:
        dprint("recoverableTrustFailure")
        
    case .fatalTrustFailure:
        dprint("fatalTrustFailure")
        
    case .otherError:
        dprint("otherError")
        
    @unknown default:
        dprint("default")
    }
    
    completionHandler(false)
}
```

Problem is that SecTrustGetTrustResult always return:

```
SecTrustResultType.recoverableTrustFailure
```

What am I doing wrong?